# how to form the dataframe in turn wise using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the dataframe like below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {
        'Name': ['Jenny', 'Matt', 'Jenny', 'Jenny','Jenny', 'Matt'],
        'Year': [2020, 2021, 2022, 2020, 2021,2030],
        'Income': [10000, 11000, 9000, 12000, 13000,5000],
        'Gender': ['F', 'M', 'F', 'F','F', 'M']
    }
)
print(df)
```

Output of this DataFrame looks like below

```
Name  Year  Income Gender
0  Jenny  2020   10000      F
1   Matt  2021   11000      M
2  Jenny  2022    9000      F
3  Jenny  2020   12000      F
4  Jenny  2021   13000      F
5   Matt  2030    5000      M
```

Now i want to use Gender column it should start from Female (F) and ends with Male (M) that finally should be single row, if two or three sequential female(F)/Male(M) rows occurs then all the corresponding Year and Income row values need to be added and form a single row for Female/male.

```
Expecting output as below:
  Year  Income Gender 
  2020   10000     F 
  2021   11000     M  
  6063   34000     F 
  2030    5000     M
```

I have thousands of columns so i am using iterator
Below is the code i used but i am getting results only for two sequential gender and even on that i am having issues.

```
i=0
j=0
column_lst = list(df)
column_lst = [e for e in column_lst if e not in ('Name', 'Gender')]
column_lst
df_lst1 = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if(row['Gender']=='F'):
        j=0
        i=i+1
        for lst in column_lst:
            print(lst)
            print(i)
            if(i>1):
                a = int(row[lst])
                print('a',a)
                c=a+b
                print('c',c)
                f=row['Gender']+'_'+str(c)
                del df_lst1[-1]
            else:
                f=row['Gender']+'_'+str(row[lst])
                b=int(row[lst])
                print('b',b)
            print("df_lst1111",df_lst1)
            df_lst1.append(f)
    elif (row['Gender']=='M'):
        i=0
        j=j+1
        for lst in column_lst:
            if(j>1):
                a1=int(row[lst])
                print('a1',a1)
                c1=a1+b1
                print('c1',c1)
                f1=row['Gender']+'_'+str(c1)
                del df_lst1[-1]
            else:
                f1=row['Gender']+'_'+str(row[lst])
                b1=int(row[lst])
                print('b1',b1)
            print("df_lst1",df_lst1)
            df_lst1.append(f1)
```

I am getting output as below:

```
['F_2020',
 'F_10000',
 'M_2021',
 'M_11000',
 'F_2022',
 'F_22000',
 'M_2030',
 'M_5000']
```

it would be great if someone suggest how to implement

Other Ex:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {
        'Name': ['Jenny', 'Matt', 'Jenny', 'Jenny', 'Matt', 'Jenny', 'Jenny', 'Matt', 'Matt'],
        'Year': [2020, 2021, 2022, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2020, 2021, 2022],
        'Income': [10000, 11000, 9000, 12000, 13000, 11000, 14000, 15000, 13000],
        'Gender': ['F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M']
    }
)
```

Expected result would be:

```
Year Income Gender 
2020 10000 F
2021 11000 M
4042 21000 F
2021 13000 M
4042 25000 F
4042 28000 M
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With pandas you should only iterate as a last resort.

Something like this should get you going:

```py
df.groupby((df.Gender!=df.Gender.shift()).cumsum()).agg({'Year': sum, 'Income': sum, 'Gender': 'first'}).reset_index(drop=True).sort_values('Gender')


   Year  Income Gender
0  2020   10000      F
2  6063   34000      F
1  2021   11000      M
3  2030    5000      M
```

Let's take that apart:

```py
df.groupby((df.Gender!=df.Gender.shift()))
```

will create groups of rows, where *Gender* is the same for consecutive rows. I.e. the groups will be `[0], [1], [2,3,4], [5]`

`.cumsum()` will return a cumulative sum over each of the groups.

With `df.groupby((df.Gender!=df.Gender.shift()).cumsum()).agg({'Year': sum, 'Income': sum, 'Gender': 'first'})` we tell pandas how we want to calculate the cumulative sum for each column.
In this case, sum *Year* (whatever sense that makes) and *Income*, and just take the first value of *Gender* from each group (as we have grouped by *Gender* the first value will be the same as all other values for this group.

Finally `reset_index(drop=True).sort_values('Gender')` will remove the artificial index column, which `groupby` has created and sort the value by *Gender*, so that `F` comes before `M`

Comment: I should not sort by Gender, it should be Female and male. There should be only one row for Female and one row for Male, if we have sequence Male/Female then the corresponding values should get add up so that it will come as a single row. (i cannot use specific column name because i have thousands of columns to do this action)

Comment: In the question, you have two rows for female and two rows for male, in the expected output. Not one. In the latter example you show three rows for each, not one. So I cannot understand your comment. Also I do not understand what you mean by „cannot use a specific column name“. You have shown your data and it’s columns

Comment: Thank you, i removed .sort_values('Gender') and its working as expected.